# General formula for the probability of a runner achieving their average time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The more I think about this, the less sense it makes, but I'll ask anyway since it could just be a simple "no.".

I run the 100-meters 50 times.
I get the mean of my times, let's say it's 13.00 seconds.
I also get some more information, like the minimum (12.50) and maximum (14.00) times.

I want to make a function using this data that gives me a pretty similar list of times when I run it 50 times.

Obviously, there's no way to say exactly what the distribution is, but since this sort of thing comes up a lot, I thought there might be some way to get a better estimate than just joining up the points.

Maybe some way of joining up the points, such that the more points you get, the more accurate your function gets?

Comment: Your query, which another response has addressed, highlights the difference between the mean and the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you correctly stated, there is no standard way to determine which distribution these times would follow. However, in your example where the minimum is $12.5$ seconds and the maximum is $14$ seconds and the mean time is $13$ seconds, you could think of the following model: $\mathbb{P}(T \in [12.5, 13]) = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}(T \in [13, 14]) = \frac{1}{3}$ and it is uniform in each of these two intervals. Other than this, without any additional relevant data, any model that meets your initial conditions (in the above example, minimum, maximum and mean) would do the trick, even though some models could be more sensible than others.